# Google Play Service out of date

Tags: android, google-play

I am testing my app on 2 devices:
Samsung SM-T211 (Android 4.1.2) and Galaxy Nexus (Android 4.3)
I have no problems on the first one, but on the Nexus I get a

> Google Play Service out of date. Requires 4242000 but found 315830

How can that be?

Comment: if you are handling checking for google play service properly you should be prompted to download the latest version in the play store

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25626222/does-google-play-services-version-being-out-dated-not-let-the-app-to-run